# Real time notification from SQL Server using ASP.Net Web API 2 to Android using Android Studio

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api

Any idea on how to make my Android app notified in real-time from back-end every time data is inserted into the table in database? I'm using Web API 2 in ASP.NET to communicate from my Android app to the database using SQL.

Here's my code in Android accessing Web API:

```java
public interface SMSService {

    @GET("/api/sms")
    void getSMSQueue(Callback<List<SMSDetail>> callback);

    @DELETE("/api/sms/{id}")
    void deleteSMSQueue(@Path("id") Integer id, Callback<SMSDetail> callback);

}
```

Comment: This really should be tagged Android, not Android Studio

Comment: Try to send GCM/FCM push messages to app, when a new table is inserted.

Comment: thanks @MujammilAhamed for this idea. I tried to research on GCM earlier, I was  just confused It couldn't answer my question, is GCM can communicate to SQL db? by the way, thanks for your time on this, i appreciate it.

Comment: No you need to add listener and send GCM when a new table is created

Comment: is this done by SQL? where to add listener?..in my case when the table has a new data inserted. Then, I want to notify my Android app, Im using Web API to communicate with SQL db.

Comment: i think ill do a hard code in c# in my Web API to send FCM notification whenever my table inserted. Is the logic correct?..Thanks to you @MujammilAhamed.

Comment: I have less knowledge in SQL,You may open a new question to need more info about that.

Comment: Improved wording and spelling. Corrected language before code.